# Clear variables in listbox

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I made a listbox to access variables from the workspace. I would like
to clear some variables from the workspace by highlighting variables
in the listbox. Could anyone let me know how to that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example GUI:

```
function clear_vars_gui
    %# create user interface
    hFig = figure('Name','Clear Variables', 'NumberTitle','off', ...
        'Menubar','none', 'Position',[300 300 200 300]);
    hList = uicontrol('style','listbox', 'Min',1, 'Max',10, ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0.1 1 0.9], 'Parent',hFig);
    uicontrol('style','push', 'String','clear', 'Callback',@button_cb, ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 0.1], 'Parent',hFig);

    %# initialize listbox
    populateList();

    function populateList()
        %# populate listbox with variable names
        vars = evalin('base','who');
        set(hList, 'String',vars, 'Value',1)
        drawnow
    end
    function button_cb(o,e)
        %# get list of variables and the currently selected items
        vars = get(hList, 'String');
        idx = get(hList, 'Value');
        if isempty(vars), return; end

        %# filter to selected vars
        vars = vars(idx);

        %# clear variables in base workspace
        evalin('base', ['clearvars ' sprintf('%s ',vars{:})]);

        %# update listbox
        populateList();
    end
end
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: this my GUI ,i want to create pushbotton to clear some variables from the workspace;without select anything in listbox;and thanks

Comment: you gave little description and no code, so I had to come up with my own example. Please study the code above and adapt it to your own GUI... It is difficult to offer help without seeing what you've done so far

Comment: THANKS Amro,i have another question,how i can modify the parameter of  Transition times of three phase break using GUI,?

Comment: 3 rd question ,if i have an impédance Z=0.045+j0.033 AND y=0+J0.023 OF Three-Phase PI Section Line ,how i can compute Positive- and zero-sequence resistances (Ohms/km) [ r1  r0 ],inductances ,and  capacitances?

Comment: @SidaliChaib: huh, I'm not sure how that is related to the above! Please create a separate question to ask for help, remember to mark the above as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/135945) if you think it solved your GUI problem..